# DotNET 7 Console app failed to run on Linux as self-contained

Tags: c#

I created a small app that makes cleanup in a specific directory:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = args.FirstOrDefault();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Path not defined");
            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Directory not found");
            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Getting ready files");
                var readyFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.ready").Select(c => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(c));

                Console.WriteLine("Getting done files");
                var doneFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.done").Select(c => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(c));

                Console.WriteLine("Getting dirs");
                var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

                foreach (var dir in dirs)
                {
                    var name = Path.GetFileName(dir);
                    if (readyFiles.Any(f => f.Equals(name)))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (!doneFiles.Any(f => f.Equals(name)))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine($"Removing {name}");
                    Directory.Delete(dir, true);
                    if (File.Exists($"{dir}.password"))
                    {
                        File.Delete($"{dir}.password");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }

            Thread.Sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
        }
    }
```

I published file as self-contained, single file and linux-x64:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\net7.0\publish\linux-x64\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I set executable on linux `chmod +x foldercleanup`, when run it I get

> Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E

And the trace made with `strace -f -o logfile ./foldercleanup` : https://pastebin.com/jJu13R85

I checked this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/79612 but no success in applying their possible fix.

Comment: Out of interest have you experimented with some slightly different publishing settings? Like 32-bit Linux and `PublishSingleFile = false`

Comment: Line 1506 of your strace log (bold added): "2523612 mmap(NULL, 37580972032, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 **ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)**" - you said you've tried the fix in the linked issue, so you are setting the environment variable correctly? `DOTNET_GCHeapHardLimit=1C0000000`

Comment: How to set when I have single file output ? I tried with export command in shell `export DOTNET_GCHeapHardLimit=1C0000000`... I guess abolve solution would work if have dotnet installed but I preferred self-contained single file.